# Copy current terminal prompt to clipboard

Tags: bash, bashrc, shortcut-keys, xfce4-terminal

Is there a way to copy the currently written content of the bash prompt? Say I wrote:

```
ping www.google.com
```

so that the lines in terminal looks like:

```
petr@sova:~$ ping www.google.com
```

and didn't hit return yet. I want to copy that text to clipboard. Is that possible?

*The usual usecase would be hitting up several times and finding a command which I want to copy.*

Answer (score 48):

To cut, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>. To paste, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>. This copies whole line to bash clipboard. If you're using X and default Ubuntu terminal, you can use your mouse to mark contents and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste.

Comment: I am using Xubuntu and while ctrl+u and ctrl+y works in the terminal, I need to be able to cut/copy from terminal and paste in a different app, which doesn't work. Possibly, ctrl+u cuts the text into terminal's own clipboard, not the global one?

Comment: You have to use X's clipboard. Try ctrl+shift+c and ctrl+shift+v. If you're using terminal (without graphical UI), you're out of luck. If you want to append commands to script file, you can use `echo ping www.google.com >> filename.txt` to work around it.

Comment: And tip: you can prefix commands easily by pressing ctrl+u, writing `echo ` and then hitting ctrl+y to paste original command back.

Comment: @olli, easier would be to press ctrl+a to go to the beginning of prompt

Comment: @ratskin I don't know which terminal (emulator) you are using, that doesn't work for me.

Comment: It might be fn + shift + left-arrow or fn + left-arrow for you.

Answer (score 6):

- Add a `#` to the front of the command (so it becomes a comment)
- Run it
- Grab it from the history and pipe it to a clipboard utillity like
  xclip: `history | tail -n 1 | sed "s/[[:digit:]]*  //" | sed "s/^#//" | xclip`

Comment: An easier alternative is to add echo in front of the command and pipe to xclip.  `$ echo <command> | xclip -selection clipboard`

Answer (score 4):

Not sure why all answers are so complicated, from bash 4.0 you can access current content with `$READLINE_LINE`. Combine with xclip and you have ready to go, working solution. Add this to your `.bashrc`

```
if [[ -n $DISPLAY ]]; then
  copy_line_to_x_clipboard () {
    printf %s "$READLINE_LINE" | xclip -selection CLIPBOARD
  }
  bind -x '"\C-y": copy_line_to_x_clipboard' # binded to ctrl-y
fi
```

For zsh

```
if [[ -n $DISPLAY ]]; then
    copy_line_to_x_clipboard() {
        echo -n $BUFFER | xclip -selection clipboard
        zle reset-prompt
    }
    zle -N copy_line_to_x_clipboard
    bindkey '^Y' copy_line_to_x_clipboard
fi
```

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. Even works in WSL and I can paste to my Windows side no problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using the mouse, just triple click on the line you want to copy then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. You can then paste it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: should be ctrl+shift+c to copy, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

**Vi mode solution**

Keyboard-only solution. All characters are copied exactly "as-is". Out of the box - pure shell solution, no dependencies (except `xsel` obviously).

Setup

1. Set vi option in terminal: `set -o vi`.
2. Alias copying unclosed here-document: `alias c2c='cat - <<"" | tr -d '"'"'\n'"'"' | xsel -b'`

Usage

1. Write anything you want to the command line without pressing `<return>`.
2. Press `<escape>` followed by `<d>`, `<d>`. Whole line should now disappear. To be able to type again, press `<i>`.
3. Type name of the alias (`c2c` in my example) and press `<return>`.
4. Press `<escape>`, `<p>` then `<return>`, `<return>`.

Voilà. Deleted text can be now pasted anywhere by pressing `<ctrl>+<v>` (GUI), or `<ctrl>+<shift>+<v>` (reasonable CLI). If Your CLI isn't reasonable, [make it so](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=ctrl%20shift%20v%20doesn%27t%20work).

**fzf solution**

Some likes like vi mode, others not really. But I think [fuzzy finder](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) is must have. It doesn't allow to do *exactly* what you've asked, it can do something better! Instead of "hitting up several times" fzf can browse command history with order of magnitude better efficiency. Moreover, it can be used inside my `c2c` alias to copy to clipboard. Whatever is typed to the terminal at the moment cannot be nicely copied (without mouse), but if something is in history, it is a matter of seconds to get it.

Comment: Pressing <esc>, <v> with vi option enabled opens **nano**. However, its cut-and-paste abilities are also confined within terminal.

Answer (score 0):

In `xfce4-terminal`, you need to select with the mouse the text you'd like to copy, then <kbd>right-click</kbd> and then select the <kbd>Copy</kbd> item in the context-menu.

Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, kosciej16's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1428355/861784) is the most user-friendly option.
But it doesn't work when you SSH into a remote machine (p.e. a VPS or a Raspberry Pi) without an X server.

This solution (added to your `.bashrc`) doesn't depend on X on remote machines:

```bash
copy_line_to_x_clipboard () {
  # using OSC 52
  printf "\e]52;c;%s\a" "$(printf %s "$READLINE_LINE" | openssl base64 -A)"
}
# bind it to Ctrl-Shift-x
bind -x '"\C-X": copy_line_to_x_clipboard'
```

But it works only in terminal emulators that support OSC 52 like Alacritty, kitty, st, tmux, Windows Terminal, iTerm2. See [ojroques/vim-oscyank](https://github.com/ojroques/vim-oscyank) for a list of terminal emulators that support OSC 52.